# what would cause a linked server to return a limited amount of data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

We are having an issue with a server that we linked to our sql server 2012 instance.

The server that we linked through an odbc or oledb connection is Pervasive SQL.

**Selecting from the linked server this way works as long as the result set is small:**

```
select * from linked_server.database..mytable
```

If the result set is more than around **2mb** (might be slightly more or less) then we get this error:

```
Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "KSLAP208" reported an error. The provider reported an unexpected catastrophic failure.
Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "KSLAP208".
```

However, the silly thing is that SSMS 2012 for instance displays all the columns that need to be returned and then immediatley errors out.

**What would cause SSMS 2012 to produce an error on a result set that is too big? (more than 1-2mb)??**

here's what i see in the odbc administrator:

[image]

Comment: It might be your driver.  We have had unwanted adventures with linked servers to redbrick.  These were driver related.  What happens if you try the same thing with openquery?

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. yes we did try openquery and same result

Comment: @DanBracuk we did try to reinstall the driver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Option 1, disable pre-fetch

Sometimes, disabling pre-fetch will solve problems like this.

> You can disable the prefetch by clearing the "Enable pre-fetch of data
> for queries" check box in the Performance tab when creating a DSN or
> adding "PREFETCH=0" to the connection string when creating a DSN-less connection.

More on this:

> In the ODBC Data Source Administrator panel on the server, configure
> your linked server from System DSN. Under the Performance tab, uncheck
> the box 'Enable pre-fetch of data for queries'.  OK, OK. Delete and
> re-create your linked server in SQL Management Studio.

[Source](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldataaccess/thread/f9ddbb1e-b276-47e7-a85a-475c1e8c6793/)

## Option 2, Allow inprocess

- Go to Linked Servers
- Providers
- MSOLAP (or similar)
- Properties
- Make sure "Allow inprocess" is enabled. Even if it is, turn it off. Save. And then turn it back on. Sometimes resetting this can help.

Comment: is that the same thing as array fetch?

Comment: i just disabled array fetch and got the same result

Comment: added a bit more detail about disabling pre-fetch

Comment: brian thank you again for such a thorough answer. i've added a picture to my question

Comment: I'm at a loss, but maybe my answer will help others with a similar problem. If I were in your shoes, I would setup another database server and install SQL Server Express R2 on it and hopefully a different driver for the linked server. This may seem like a lot of trouble, but it really won't take you that long, and you can rule out an awful lot of suspects by doing this (whether it works or not). As you probably know, fixing problems like this is about iteratively removing half of the suspects. Eventually you are left with only one. Good luck!

Comment: thank you brian. i turned off ALLOW IN PROCESS and got this error OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "KSLAP208" returned message "Specified driver could not be loaded due to system error  1114: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed. (Pervasive ODBC Interface, C:\Program Files\Pervasive Software\PSQL\bin\odbcci64.dll).".
Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "KSLAP208".

Comment: also we have a sql server 2005 that uses the same linked server without a problem

Comment: That's good, I mention in my answer that you need to turn it off then turn it back on. Sometimes doing this will cause the problem to go away. I'm not sure why, but some have had luck with it.

Comment: yes i have also read this, i did turn it back on and started to get the original error.

Comment: Well, at least we have ruled things out. Sorry this didn't fix it in your case. If you have time, I do recommend attempting what I mentioned in a previous comment regarding a new temporary server and separate driver (if possible)

Comment: what do you mean by separate driver>