# SQL Server Linked Server : OLE DB provider 'MSDAORA' reported an error

Tags: sql-server, oracle11g, openquery

I have an issues with linked server to Oracle...

at first the server running SQL Servre 2000 and Oracle8i, and the linked server works well...

But after IT Department installs an Oracle 11g Client on the server...

When I execute my open query in SQL Server, I get an error message

> [OLE/DB provider returned message: Oracle error occurred, but error message could not be retrieved from Oracle.]
>   OLE DB error trace [OLE/DB Provider 'MSDAORA' IDBInitialize::Initialize returned 0x80004005:   ].
>
> Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   OLE DB provider 'MSDAORA' reported an error.

Hope you guys can help me out, thanks.

Comment: Can be related to this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14794381/what-would-cause-a-linked-server-to-return-a-limited-amount-of-data

Comment: no it was not related, btw thanks you for the information too... and i have come out with a solution... just as simple as register the ORACLE 11 DLL then the linked server works again.